# How to use the += operator on a property that doesn't have a setter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting a `Can't set attribute` error when I'm using the `+=` operator on a read-only property that is of a type for which I've defined a `__iadd__()` method.

Simplified (but runnable) version of my code:

```py
class Emitter(list):
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.append( other )
        return self

class Widget:
    def __init__(self):
        self._on_mouseenter = Emitter()

    @property
    def on_mouseenter(self): return self._on_mouseenter


my_widget = Widget()
my_widget.on_mouseenter += lambda source: print("on_mouseenter!")
```

The last line produces the error. It goes away if I add the following line to the definition of `Widget`:

```py
@on_mouseenter.setter
def on_mouseenter(self, value): pass
```

(Runnable at https://repl.it/EONf/0)

This behaviour seems strange on two accounts. First, I thought that Python passes objects by reference, so why should the property have to be readable? And second, how come that my dummy setter even works?

Comment: The answers explain the issue, however, you could just define `self.on_mouseenter = Emitter()` directly and avoid the property.

Comment: Be careful with your terminology. While Python does pass around references to objects, "pass by reference" refers to something subtly different. What Python does doesn't really have a good standard name; some people call it "call by object", "call by sharing", or as the Java folks call it, "pass by value, but the value that gets passed is a reference".

Comment: @BenHoyt: I wanted to make the property read-only so that user code can't overwrite it. Is that an antipattern in Python?

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of an antipattern, but not necessarily. Usually Python goes more by the "we're all consenting adults here" principal. For example, Python doesn't really have private members, users can muck with things if they want (or need to).

Comment: Thanks @BenHoyt, I'm gonna go back to a vanilla attribute then.

Comment: In Python, I would probably allow `self.on_mouseenter` to be None or just a straight function object, or a list of callables. And then a `dispatch_event(widget.on_mouseenter, event)` function which handles those three cases. Or even just None and a single function (YAGNI). Then for most cases callers can just set it to a callback function directly with `self.on_mouseenter = f` rather than `self.on_mouseenter.add(f)`.

Comment: Setting the property to a function directly however would not cover the case of independently written blocks of user code registering callbacks without knowing of each other, correct ? (That is in fact the reason why I wanted to prevent direct assignment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__iadd__` returns a replacement object to be rebound to the variable.  This of course requires a setter.

In this case it works because you're ignoring the set, but still leaving the original object in place, which you've changed in place.

This behavior is required because some objects are immutable, but in place add still works on them.

`i += 5` takes the number i is bound to, adds 5 to it, and rebinds i to the NEW result number.  That is, it is exactly equivalent to `i = i + 5`, which has an assignment in it.

Comment: Thanks @Max. Would you say that my solution is correct then?

Comment: Not really: it should assign the value passed to it, or you may get some very surprising results if `__iadd__` doesn't return self.

Comment: Using += to mean append is not particularly pythonic.  People will be used to working with lists by using .append(), not +=.

Comment: Thanks @Max, that is good to know. I'm going to remove the Emitter class and save myself the trouble then.

Comment: @Max Sorry for opening the topic again. What is then reason to implement augmented operators? For example in case x += 5, its equivalent x = x.__iadd__(5) so basically x = x + 5. Only reason to have two version is that x +=5 behaves differently than x = x + 5 and that doesn't have sense as well. So as I see it, the augmented operators are pointless.

Comment: @PatrikValkovič If your object is mutable, you can mutate it in place and return it, which can be more efficient (for example, a list that adds onto the end of itself).  If it's immutable, then there isn't much point.

Answer (score 3):

It's caused by how Python's [augmented assignment operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) work. After calling the appropriate [special method](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-special-method), they assign the return value to the object at the left hand side of the operator.

> If `x` is an instance of a
>   class with an `__iadd__()` method, `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)`. Otherwise, `x.__add__(y)` and `y.__radd__(x)` are
>   considered, as with the evaluation of `x + y`.

Therefore

```
my_widget.on_mouseenter += lambda source: print("on_mouseenter!")
```

is equivalent to

```
my_widget.on_mouseenter = my_widget.on_mouseenter.__iadd__(lambda source: print("on_mouseenter!"))
```

and you need a setter to perform assignment. It doesn't have to do anything, though, because the `__iadd__` method is defined and modifies the list in-place.

Comment: For further reading, see [this answer](https://docs.python.org/3.5/faq/programming.html#faq-augmented-assignment-tuple-error) in the Python FAQ.

Comment: @vaultah: I accepted Max' answer solely because it was a second or so faster. Thanks to both of you.